# How can I set the range for the Sheet3 lots of columns called(attribute value1,attribute value2..N)

Tags: excel, vba

I want this code to search the column name called((attribute value1,attribute value2..N) 
If that column contains fraction values, it should convert it to decimal. I'm using this macros(VBA).
The code is working but it is converting only one column(attribute value1).
It will take more time because I have multiple columns(attribute value2...N) that have fraction values.

Please help me out I am struck here.

```
Sub deci()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Dash As Long
    Dim Whole As Double
    Dim lngDataColumn As Long
    Dim pi

    lngDataColumn = 4
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngDataColumn).End(xlUp).row
    For r = 2 To LR
        s = Cells(r, lngDataColumn)
        arr = Split(s, ",")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Whole = 0
            P = InStr(arr(i), " IN")
            If P > 0 Then
                Worksheet = (Left((arr(i)), P - 1))
            Else
                Worksheet = arr(i)
            End If
            Dash = InStr(Worksheet, "-")
            If Dash > 0 Then
                Whole = Frac(Left(Worksheet, Dash - 1))
                Worksheet = Mid(Worksheet, Dash + 1)
            End If
            af = Right(arr(i), Len(arr(i)) - P + 1)
            evfrac = Whole + Left(CStr(Evaluate(Worksheet)), 5)
            '   evfrac = Whole + Format(Evaluate(frac), "0.###")
            ss = ss & evfrac & af & ", "
        Next i
        Cells(r, lngDataColumn) = Left(ss, Len(ss) - 2)
        ss = ""
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

```
Function Frac(ByVal X As String) As Double
    Dim P As Integer, N As Double, Num As Double, Den As Double
    X = Trim$(X)
    P = InStr(X, "/")
    If P = 0 Then
        N = Val(X)
    Else
    Den = Val(Mid$(X, P + 1))
    If Den = 0 Then Err.Raise 11    ' Divide by zero
        X = Trim$(Left$(X, P - 1))
        P = InStr(X, " ")
        If P = 0 Then
            Num = Val(X)
        Else
            Num = Val(Mid$(X, P + 1))
            N = Val(Left$(X, P - 1))
        End If
    End If
    If Den <> 0 Then
        N = N + Num / Den
    End If
    Frac = N
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's only doing one column is because that's exactly what your telling it to do with this section of the code:

```
lngDataColumn = 4
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngDataColumn).End(xlUp).row
```

Because your setting `lngDataColumn` as a fixed figure, your code is only executed on column 4. If you want to do more columns as a loop, you need to increment this value in the same maner you are incrementing `r` in your `for` loop.

For example:

```
lngDataColumn = 10
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    For 4 To lngDataColumn
        LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngDataColumn).End(xlUp).row
        'Rest of code
    Next lngDataColumn
```

Comment: thanks but still i am getting the compile error called next without for Sub deci()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Dash As Long
    Dim Whole As Double
    Dim lngDataColumn As Long
    Dim pi

    lngDataColumn = 10
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    For r = 4 To LR
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngDataColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    'rest code
      
      
            Next lngDataColumn
End Sub

Comment: Please format your stuff correctly! You haven't included the line `For 4 To lngDataColumn` what you've written is `For r = 4 to LR`

Comment: For 4 To lngDataColumn i have used but it showing               compile Error:Syntax Error